# RStudio crashes after setting options(bitmapType="cairo") and running a ggplot with transparency

Tags: r, transparency, cairo

I am running R 4.2.2. in RStudio 2022.07.2 with Ubuntu 20.04.
When I try to run a ggplot with transparency such as:

```
ggplot(as.data.frame(rowData(rpdata)))+
geom_density(aes(x=length, fill=status), alpha=0.5)
```

I receive the warning message:

```
    Warning message:
In grid.Call.graphics(C_polygon, x$x, x$y, index) :
  semi-transparency is not supported on this device: reported only once per page
```

And the output, the plot has the transparencies missing. I followed the answers suggested in [Semi-transparency in RStudio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22581567/semi-transparency-in-rstudio) about installing Cairo and setting:

```
options(bitmapType="cairo")
```

However, after running that, my RStudio crashes.

PS: if I save the plot using pdf(). the plot is correct and no error is displayed, but I want to see the correct plot directly in RStudio and then maybe save it with png().

Comment: Have you tried using `ragg`? It has full transparency support and very nice anti-aliasing / text handling. Do `install.packages("ragg")` in the R console, then in the RStudio toolbar, select Tools -> Global Options -> General -> Graphics and set "Backend" to "AGG".

Comment: I had some problems with the dependencies that can be solved by : `sudo aptitude install libharfbuzz-dev libfribidi-dev libfreetype6-dev libpng-dev libtiff5-dev libjpeg-dev`, but it worked. If you post an answer I'll validate it. Thanks!